# PostgreSQL - Export data with copy command uses huge memory resources

Tags: java, docker, postgresql

I am using CopyManager from Java to export data from PostgreSQL (data size around 1GB) and there is no problem with it Running `"COPY (" + sql + ") TO STDOUT WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER)"` statement behind the scene and receiving as output stream.. But while exporting, PostgreSQL memory usage increasing massively (from 150MB TO 900MB) and doesn't free them. How to detect this issue and solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That’s not an issue but how databases generally work. PostgreSQL (and many other engines) will cache data so that subsequent queries are faster as they are read from memory rather than storage. If you want to get your PostgreSQL memory usage down, you will need to restart the database engine after the operation. Depending on how the data is being read, you may also need to clear the OS buffers via `drop_caches`, though this is not recommended on production systems …

Comment: yeah, maybe issue is not correct word ok but I would expect that at least minor level deallocation happening after a while. Does making utilization on configurations help ?

Comment: Memory is meant to be used. The database engine and the OS underneath will only do so when higher-priority processes are requesting more than is available.